# Adding Google Sheets to iOS using CocoaPods

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, google-sheets-api

I tried to add Google Sheets to a project, using CocoaPods, but receive an error.

Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'ict' do

pod 'Google/SignIn'
pod 'GoogleAPIClientForREST/Sheets'
pod 'GTMAppAuth'



end
```

Error after installing Pod:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing AppAuth (0.7.1)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics (3.9.0)

[!] Error installing FirebaseAnalytics
[!] /usr/bin/tar xfz /var/folders/_p/k47cs36s3r585kmsg84x7v580000gp/T/d20170514-96989-lvaiwn/file.tgz -C /var/folders/_p/k47cs36s3r585kmsg84x7v580000gp/T/d20170514-96989-lvaiwn

tar: Unrecognized archive format
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

Answer (score 2):

By following these steps and copying your `Podfile` contents, I did not get any error:

*NOTE: The `$atom Podfile` part was for editing the `Podfile` with Atom text editor.*

```
$ pod init
$ atom Podfile 
$ pod install
```

Output:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing AppAuth (0.7.1)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics (3.9.0)
Installing FirebaseCore (3.6.0)
Installing FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.10)
Installing GTMAppAuth (0.5.0)
Installing GTMOAuth2 (1.1.4)
Installing GTMSessionFetcher (1.1.9)
Installing Google (3.0.3)
Installing GoogleAPIClientForREST (1.2.1)
Installing GoogleSignIn (4.0.2)
Installing GoogleToolboxForMac (2.1.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

[!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `ict.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 3 dependencies from the Podfile and 11 total pods installed.
MacBook-Pro:ict Bajo$
```

Comment: Thanks, so the problem is with my local pod cache, i'll remove and resetup pods.

Comment: Interesting, how did you find out?

Comment: Nope, I was wrong, still receiving same error after removing POD cache :|